# How to create an executable in the $package/bin directory?

Tags: rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use this in my CMakefile :

rosbuild_add_executable(arp_core.arp arp_core_main.c)
INSTALL(TARGETS arp_core.arp RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

but the exe does go into the bin directory, it stays in the root of the package folder.

I also defined theses :
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR})
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9212/how-to-create-an-executable-in-the-$package/bin-directory-?/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're not doing any installing so the install command doesn't come in to play.  This should do it:

```
set(RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

see the docs at

```
cmake --help-full | less
```

You'd need to post your whole cmakelists for me to be sure.

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1